# Structure arrays in c

Tags: c

I am to read from a .ssv file and create a student database which contains: Name, ID, Exam1, Exam2, Project1, Project2, Average and Grade(letter). The average is not in the file, hence it having to be calculated. I am unsure of my average calculation and my structure declaration. Any other fixes would be welcomed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[26];
    int I_D[25];
    int exam[3];
    int project[3]
    float average[3];
    char grade[3];
} STUDENT;

void printStuAry(int size, STUDENT stuAry[]);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("ERROR\n");
        return 1;
    }

    STUDENT stuAry[5];

    FILE* f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    char line[65];
    int ind = 0;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != NULL) {
        sscanf(line, "%25[^;] ; %d %d %d %d %d %c",
                                 stuAry[ind].name,
                                 &stuAry[ind].I_D,
                                 &stuAry[ind].exam[0],
                                 &stuAry[ind].exam[1],
                                 &stuAry[ind].project[0],
                                 &stuAry[ind].project[1]
                                 &stuAry[ind].grade);


    float stuAry.average = stuAry.exam[0] + stuAry.exam[1] + stuAry.project[0] + stuAry.project[1]/4;
    ind++;
    }
    printStuAry(5, stuAry);


    if (fclose(f) == EOF) {
        printf("Error closing file %s.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void printStuAry(int size, STUDENT stuAry[])
{
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("Student \"%s\" score %d, %d and %d and %d on midterms, "
                     "and %c on the final.\n",
                     stuAry[i].name, stuAry[i].exam[0],
                     stuAry[i].exam[1], stuAry[i].project[0],
                     stuAry[i].project[1], stuAry[i].average,
                     stuAry[i].final);
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggestion not a solution. order of structure elements would save some space. arrange char variables together.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate an average by hand? Have you already tested your code? Do you use a debugger to see some vars values while running?

Comment: @Ripi2 I have compiled it and have received a few errors. one of them being `error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int *’ and ‘int’)`

Answer (score 1):

I will not rewrite the code for you, just indicate your errors.

> int I_D[25];
>   why an array for the id, just an integer
>
> int exam[3];
>
> int project[3]

- Since you have only 2 exams and 2 projects, the sizes should be 2.
- missing `;`

> float average[3];
>
> char grade[3];

should not be arrays...

> while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != NULL) {
>           sscanf(line, "%25[^;] ; %d %d %d %d %d %c",  etc...

The correct way to read a well-formatted file is like this:

```
while(7 == fscanf(f, "%25[^;] ; %d %d %d %d %d %c", etc..))
```

> float stuAry.average = stuAry.exam[0] + stuAry.exam[1] + stuAry.project[0] + stuAry.project[1]/4;

- parenthesize the sum
- divide by 4.0 to avoid integer division and get a float division with a float result
- index the array by [ind] to work on the current student.

`stuAry[ind].average = (stuAry[ind].exam[0] + stuAry[ind].exam[1] + stuAry[ind].project[0] + stuAry[ind].project[1])/4.0;`

There are may be other errors but this should get you some good start

Comment: I modified my code based on you suggestions, and I am left with one compile error `error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘int *’ and ‘int *’)`,          Error at line49   `stuAry[ind].avg = (stuAry[ind].exam1 + stuAry[ind].exam2 + stuAry[ind].project1 + stuAry[ind].project2)/4.0;`

Comment: how did you declare `exam1` and `exam2`, `project1`, `project2` in the struct? As arrays? They should not be arrays.

Comment: Okay my program runs but having a issue with how the records are being printed. Since the file is records.ssv how would a structure my sscanf.

Comment: The grade might be `"A+"` or `"C-"` in which case, `char grade[3];` is appropriate.  But I agree there's no obvious reason to have 3 averages.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler agree, but since OP is *scanfing* it as %c, thought it might be only A, B, C etc... in the problem's statement.

Comment: Okay my program runs but having a issue with how the records are being printed. Since the file is records.ssv (the file separates the data with semicolons ;) how would a structure my sscanf.  `sscanf(line, "%25[^;]  %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %c",` @ A.S.H

Comment: @josmar: After `%25[^;]`, you need to scan a semicolon.  After the `%d`, you need a space and a semicolon (rather than a comma), the space to allow for `123 ;`.  You don't need a space before the `%d` because `%d` skips spaces anyway, though they do no harm and you might prefer to keep them for consistency.  Do you only get single-letter grades, or can you have `A+`?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler single letter grades

Comment: That is: `sscanf(line, "%25[^;] ; %d ; %d ; %d ; %d ; %d ; %c",`

Comment: @A.S.H Seems I receive a segmentation fault when using that

Comment: Maybe because you have blank lines at the end. I dont have the file to see. but anyway, do it the "right way" as I told you: `while(7 == fscanf(f, "%25[^;] ; %d ; %d ; %d ; %d ; %d ; %c", ... ))...` (or `%c;` if you also have the semi-colon at the end of each line).

Comment: also you may have more than 5 records and your array has place only for 5 students... Now you need to use the `Debugger` to know what is going wrong.

Comment: While I remember, you should probably put a space in the format string before the scan set to skip white space such as new lines.  The scan set doesn't skip such space otherwise.